# MVC4: Compilation Error The type 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

The following line of code is throwing the following error when i try to load the page:

CS0012: The type 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Courses.Id, Model.CourseList)
```

In MVC3, I remember fixing this easily by adding the following line in the web.config file:

```
<add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
```

However in MVC4 you cannot use the  tag anymore, so I'm not sure how I can resolve it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Project -> references -> right-click -> add reference

Answer (score 8, accepted):

nvm, I was wrong you have to open up the  tag and add the  tag yourself.

Solution:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
      <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    </assemblies>
  </compilation>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a reference to Entity Framework in your MVC project. That should fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This solution has worked for me:

`<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
  <assemblies>
      <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    </assemblies>`

Answer (score 0):

[Load User Profile in the Application Pool Advance Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APCWN.png).

This approach solved this for me.